# How to add dropdown list in gridview from data of dropdownlist coming from database

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                 <Columns>  
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item ID">  
                    <EditItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SrNo") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SrNo") %>'></asp:Label>  
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField> 
                     
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Name">  
                     <ItemTemplate>                       
                       <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">  
                        </asp:DropDownList>  
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField>  

                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="qty">  
                    <EditItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>  
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="UOM"></asp:Label>  
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField>  
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty">  
                    <EditItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("qty") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("qty") %>'></asp:Label>  
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField> 

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty">  
                    <EditItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Rate") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Rate") %>'></asp:Label>  
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField> 

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">  
                    <EditItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>  
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Value"></asp:Label>  
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField>  

                 </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

Error   CS0103  The name 'DropDownList2' does not exist in the current context  WebApplication1 E:\.net project\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\demo1.aspx.cs   74  Active

I have no idea what to do

Comment: See my demo here and what happens in GridView_RowDataBound. https://www.vanderwaal.eu/mini-projecten/gridview-edit-and-update-demo. You have to use FindControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so as you note, when you drop in a button, dropdownlist or whatever into a GridView?

Then to wire up events for that control, you can't just click on that control, or in code behind use that control, since there can be "many" rows.

So, then, how do we reference the control?

Well, to make a long story short, since there are "many" instances of the control, then we have to deal with EACH single instance of that control.

And we need a bit more logic here.

We need to do several things:

Get our hands on the control.

Fill the control with the list of choices.

AND THEN if need be, set the dropdown value to the CURRENT row of the grid view.

And OPTIONAL of course is to probably deal with when the grid row has NO choice, so, we need to add a please select.

So, ALL of the above has to be done, and worse yet, has to be done for EACH copy/row of the dropdown list.

Thankfully, this is not difficult.

The trick here is to use the "row data binding" event. That event triggers for EACH row. So, this is a VERY handy event, since we can do things like hide/show controls based on data, maybe color some controls based on data, and last but not least, ALSO load up the combo box, and set the current chosen value for the given row.

I don't have your data, but let's say we have a simple list of hotels, and we want to use a combo box to set/choose the city.

So, our code can work like this:

First, our simple markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" 
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server"
                    DataTextField="City" >
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" ItemStyle-Width="180" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And now our code to load:

```
Dim rstCity As DataTable
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT City FROM City ORDER BY City"

    rstCity = MyRst(strSQL)

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"
    GridView1.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Note in above, how I declare a data table at the form class level. We ONLY need this value DURING the row binding process.

So, our row data bound event is then this:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim cboCity As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("cboCity")

        cboCity.DataSource = rstCity
        cboCity.DataBind()
        cboCity.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select City"))

        ' now check this row of data - is city set?
        Dim gData As DataRowView = e.Row.DataItem
        If Not IsDBNull(gData("City")) Then
            cboCity.Text = gData("City")
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

And the result is this:

[image]

OK, so now our code to load above. Note how we FIRST load up a table with the City list, and then re-use that over and over to fill out the combo for each row.

Last but not least?

I had a "helper" routine, one that is global, and that saves me all the hassle of typing connection's string stuff over and over.

So, MyRst simple returns a table, and that global code routine used was this:

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            rstData.TableName = strSQL
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and for your efforts and time!!!!!